# Doctrine 2: Proxy name collisions

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, php-5.3, collision

I'm learning Doctrine 2, and noticed that the name of a generated proxy class is the original class' full name, without the namespace separator, with `Proxy` appended to it.

What if you use a namespaced domain model, and there is a collision?

```
Order         => OrderProxy
OrderProduct  => OrderProductProxy
Order\Product => OrderProductProxy (!)
```

Is it possible to change the naming convention for such proxies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible at the moment.

The [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php) shows that this naming convention is hardcoded:

```
$proxyClassName = str_replace('\\', '', $className) . 'Proxy';
```

Anyway, I now tend to think that's it's not such a bad thing: by trying to avoid such collisions, we remove confusion in the naming of our domain classes.